# Display colors gets bad after some time of using it

Tags: display, color

i have been using it for 3 days after a fresh install and now the colors of my display is oversaturated blue is more purple and orange is more red.
It was quite good and similar to what i use to see in windows when i first installed it.
i use a external monitor with my laptop both the display is lodpi 1600x900 monitor ,1366x768 laptop display

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue on both the laptop screen as well as the external monitor?

Have you tried removing the external monitor from the laptop and reboot? is the issue still there?

If you boot up from a live USB does the issue persist?

I ask because i want to see if we can work out if its a hardware issue or something with the OS installation.

Comment: this issue is both in laptop screen and monitor too it was perfect for first two days after installing

Answer (score 0):

Hello there I also have this issue. In KDE there is a quick and easy way to set color profiles so on one of the distros I set the color profile to Color space:AppleRGB and it helped with my problem. I am not sure how to set that in Elementary OS.